# How to calculate this complex expression?

Tags: numerics, complex, precision-and-accuracy

I have a complex expression as follows,

```
exp=(2 + I) E^(-(1076673/8800) - (3078 I)/
55) (-E^(24491/8800 + (1539 I)/110) + E^(
135679/8800 + (13509 I)/1100) + E^(135679/8800 + (17271 I)/1100) - 
E^(318763/8800 + (1539 I)/110) - E^(430369/8800 + (1539 I)/110) + 
E^(100453/1760 + (1539 I)/110))^2 ((10 - 5 I) E^(
177897/8800 + (1539 I)/55) - (10 - 5 I) E^(
249793/8800 + (1539 I)/55) - (10 - 5 I) E^(
57817/1760 + (28899 I)/1100) - (10 - 5 I) E^(
57817/1760 + (32661 I)/1100) + (10 - 5 I) E^(
360981/8800 + (28899 I)/1100) + (10 - 5 I) E^(
360981/8800 + (32661 I)/1100) + (10 - 5 I) E^(
472169/8800 + (1539 I)/55) - (10 - 5 I) E^(
108813/1760 + (1539 I)/55) + (10 - 5 I) E^(
23351/352 + (1539 I)/55) - (20 - 10 I) E^(
655671/8800 + (1539 I)/55) + (10 - 5 I) E^(
727567/8800 + (1539 I)/55));
```

Very strange that,

```
                         exp//N=5.54244*10^33 - 5.76461*10^17I
                        exp 0.1=5.54244*10^33 + 0.I
               exp//Simplify//N=5.54244*10^33 + 5.76461*10^17I
              exp//ExpandAll//N=5.54244*10^33 + 7.47371*10^-10 I
    exp//ExpToTrig//Simplify//N=0.            + 0.I
exp//ComplexExpand//Simplify//N=5.54244*10^33 + 0.I
```

So, how to understand these results and what is the result of this exp ?

Ps,

In practical calculations, I need to calculate a very huge complex expression. This exp is just constructed as a simple example.

Comment: Try `Simplify[ComplexExpand[exp]] // N`.

Comment: Cannot test right now... Does it make a difference if you use `Exp[]` instead of `E^`?

Comment: @Lukas, that won't really do much, since `Exp[x]` is automagically converted to `E^x` symbolically.

Comment: @J.M. Right. Forgot about that... Thanks!

Comment: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200}, N[..., {Infinity, 10}] // Chop]` returns same result for all the examples, imaginary part 0. This is rounding/cancellation/etc.

Comment: For completeness: can you please mention how you obtained this expression?

Comment: @ciao  based on your present comment, can you write a more detailed answer and I will accept it as the answer for this question.

Comment: @Orders - I don't think it adds anything beyond mikado 's answer, so unless you have reason not to accept that, give the new participant the points...

Comment: @ciao  OK. I just think  at the beginning, this {$MaxExtraPrecision = 200} is new and important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the imaginary component is a rounding error.  Try

```
N[exp, 40]
```

and the imaginary part is returned as zero.

ADDED

If evaluated to sufficient significant figures, we see that the expressions given above all have an imaginary part indistinguishable from zero.

```
N[exp // Simplify, 40]
N[exp // ExpandAll, 40]
N[exp // ExpToTrig, 100]
N[exp // ComplexExpand, 40]
```

When working to machine precision (as I understand) Mathematica does not estimate the accuracy of the results it returns.  When working at higher precision levels, it does, allowing us to see when precision is totally lost.

Different forms of the expression obtained by different algebraic manipulations suffer from different rounding errors.  In particular, the `ExpToTrig` transformation significantly increases the rounding errors, requiring a higher level of precision to return a meaningful result.

As an example of a similar effect, consider the following, which clearly should have imaginary part zero, as shown by symbolic simplification

```
exp2 = Sum[a + R Exp[2 I j Pi /3], {j, 1, 3}] 
Simplify[exp2]
Block[{R = 4.*^34 + I 3.*^34, a = 1.*^40}, exp2]
```